# Get and use visa card in Iran

Tags: payment-cards, iran

There is some companies in Iran that say they can get visa card for you. for example [www.shepa.com](http://www.shepa.com)
I want know, is it safe to use this companies services?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question about travel.

Comment: Shepa FAQ's point out that the card does not work in Iran, Palestine, Sudan and North Korea.